# Custom ringtone for an Android contacts group?

Tags: android, android-contacts, ringtone

I want to set custom ringtone for a contacts group.
I can set a custom ringtone for a specific contact,
but I don't know how to set one for a contact group.

Here is my code for setting custom ringtone to specific contact:

```
 public class RingtoneActivity extends Activity {
    Context ctx;
    TextView songescape;
    static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1, PICK_CONTACTGROUP = 1;
    Cursor cursor;
    String SDCardRoot;

    protected static final int CONTEXTMENU_OPTION1 = 1;
    protected static final int CONTEXTMENU_OPTION2 = 2;
    protected static final int CONTEXTMENU_OPTION3 = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtone);
        ctx = this;
        songescape = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ringtonetext);
        registerForContextMenu(songescape);
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        // Set title for the context menu
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Set as");

        // Add all the menu options

        menu.add(1, 1, CONTEXTMENU_OPTION1, "Default Ringtone");
        menu.add(1, 2, CONTEXTMENU_OPTION2, "Ringtone to specific Contact");
        menu.add(1, 3, CONTEXTMENU_OPTION3, "Ringtone to Contact Group");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Get extra info about list item that was long-pressed
        AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

        // Perform action according to selected item from context menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case CONTEXTMENU_OPTION1:
            // set as default ringtone
            setRingTone();
            break;

        case CONTEXTMENU_OPTION2:
            // set ringtone to specific contact

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

            /*
             * cursor = getContentResolver().query(
             * ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
             * null, null);
             */
            break;

        case CONTEXTMENU_OPTION3:
            // set ringtone to contacts group
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setRingTone() {
        try {   
            String SDCardRoot =
                (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/cocktail.mp3");

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, SDCardRoot);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "COCKTAIL RINGTONE");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 2030);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(SDCardRoot);
            getContentResolver().delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + SDCardRoot + "\"",
                    null);
            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(ctx,
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Song is set as Ringtone!",
                    1000).show();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception!", 1000).show();
            Log.d("Exception", "catch exception" + t);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    // set custom ringtone to this id
                    Uri localUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
                    ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();

                    String hasPhone = c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver()
                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = " + id, null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String cNumber = phones.getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        System.out.println("number is:" + cNumber);

                    }

                    String name = c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String SDCardRoot1 = (Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/cocktail.mp3");

                    // from here
                    localContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                            SDCardRoot);
                    localContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,
                            "COCKTAIL RINGTONE");
                    localContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                            "audio/*");
                    localContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 2030);
                    localContentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "");
                    localContentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE,
                            true);
                    // localContentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION,
                    // true);
                    // localContentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM,
                    // true);
                    localContentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC,
                            false);
                    // to here

                    localContentValues.put(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id);
                    localContentValues.put(
                            ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, SDCardRoot1);
                    getContentResolver().update(localUri, localContentValues,
                            null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Ringtone assigned to: " + name, 0)
                            .show();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

**context menu 3 is the code to set ringtone to group.**